# How do I find the minimum and maximum of a multivariable function given two constraints?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the minimum and maximum of $f(x, y, z) = y + 4z$ subject to two constraints, $3x + z = 5$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Having a hard time figuring out how to do this problem. I think I'm doing it right but I can't seem to get the correct answer in exact terms.

Here's what I got so far (the labels are respectively up and down is left to right so $g(x,y,z)=3x+z=5$:

$$f_x = g_xλ + h_x\delta$$
$$f_y = g_yλ + h_y\delta$$
$$f_z = g_zλ + h_z\delta$$

---

$$0 = (3)λ + (2x)\delta$$
$$1 = (0)λ + (2y)\delta$$
$$4 = (1)λ + (0)\delta$$

After doing the calculations I get $λ = 4$.

---

Now I solve for $x$ and $y$ by plugging in that value into the equations.

I get:

$$x=-\frac{6}{\delta}$$
$$y=\frac{1}{2\delta}$$

Then I plug it into $f(x,y,z)$ and get:

$$\frac{6}{\delta}^2+\frac{1}{2\delta}^2=1$$

$$\delta = \frac{\sqrt{(145)}}{2}$$

---

So solving for $x$ and $y$ again:

$$x=-\frac{-12}{\sqrt{145}}$$
$$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{145}}$$

---

Then I solve for $z$ by using $g(x,y,z)$:

$$-\frac{-12}{\sqrt{145}}*3+z=5$$
$$z=5+\frac{36\sqrt{145}}{145}$$

---

So then my point is: $$(\frac{12}{\sqrt{145}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{145}},5+\frac{36\sqrt{145}}{145})$$

---

I plug this into $f(x,y,z)$:

$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{145}}+4\left(5-\frac{36\sqrt{145}}{145}\right)$$

and get: $$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{145}+20$$

---

And so I use the opposite point to get the other value (each value multiplied by -1):

$$f(x,y,z)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{145}}+4\left(5-\frac{36\sqrt{145}}{145}\right)$$

$$f(x,y,z)=-\sqrt{145}+20\quad $$

---

So my final answers are:

$$maximum = \sqrt{145}+20\quad$$
$$minimum = -\sqrt{145}+20\quad$$

Yet they're both wrong. I have no clue what's happening. I've checked my calculations a lot of times. I must be missing steps somewhere.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

If you just want to provide a final answer that'll at least help me back track. Thank you.

Comment: First, I would recommend avoiding solving for $\delta$. Instead, combine your equations to eliminate $\delta$ and yet $x=-12y$. Second, and more important, you lost a root when you solve the equations. In particular, $y=\pm 1/\sqrt{145}$. I think you messed up a sign, since you have $x=+12y$, not $x=-12y$. Regardless, the arithmetic is yuck.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I see. You didn't lose a root. But your exposition is mathematically sloppy. At the end, you just took the negative of the solution you had. Be careful; this doesn't always work.

Comment: @TedShifrin i retried with your suggestion and i'm still getting the wrong answer. I don't know what's happening. I spent 5 hours on this one problem and i'm so desperate.

Comment: $y=\pm 1/\sqrt{145}$, $x=-12y$, $z=5-3(-12y)=5+36y$. So we get $\big(-\frac{12}{\sqrt{145}},\frac1{\sqrt{145}},5+\frac{36}{\sqrt{145}}\big)$. Aha, note that as I cautioned you, you can't just take the negative. The other solution is $\big(\frac{12}{\sqrt{145}},-\frac1{\sqrt{145}},5-\frac{36}{\sqrt{145}}\big)$, and the $z$ coordinate is far from the negative. The $f$-values are $y+4z=y+4(5+36y)=20+145y$, very conveniently. So we get $20\pm\sqrt{145}$, nice and simple. I see that you've now gotten this as well. So what's the problem? ... Note that the final formula makes things pretty easy.

Comment: @TedShifrin my dumb ass was putting the numbers in the wrong slots in my system that's why it was wrong

Comment: @TedShifrin also thank u that approach is much much cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the objective function is a function of $y,z$ can we rewrite the constraints to eliminate x, and have objective and constraints in the same variables?

$3x + z = 5\\
x = \frac {5-z}{3}\\
x^2 + y^2 = 1\\
\left(\frac {5-z}{3}\right)^2 + y^2 = 1$

We have an ellipse.  We need to find where the tangent of the ellipse is parallel to $y+4z$

$-2\frac {5-z}{9}\ dz + 2y\ dy = 0\\
\frac {dy}{dz} = \frac {5-z}{9y}\\
\frac {dy}{dz} = -4\\
5-z = -36y$

and plug this back into our constraint.

$145 y^2 = 1\\
y = \pm \frac {1}{\sqrt {145}}\\
z = 5 \pm \frac {36}{\sqrt{145}}\\
f(x,\frac {1}{\sqrt {145}},5+\frac {36}{\sqrt{145}}) = 20 + \sqrt{145}\\
f(x,-\frac {1}{\sqrt {145}},5-\frac {36}{\sqrt{145}}) = 20 -\sqrt{145}$

Which is the same as you have above.

Otherwise, we could do something with Lagrange multipliers

$F(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu) = y+4z + \lambda (x^2 + y^2 - 1) + \mu (3x + z -5)\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial x} = 2\lambda x + 3\mu = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial y} = 1 + 2\lambda y = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial z} = 4 + \mu = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = x^2+y^2 - 1 = 0\\
\frac {\partial F}{\partial \mu} = 3x+z - 5 = 0$

And solve.

Comment: my answer was wrong because I had them in the wrong slots... also thank you so much. I am forever in your debt. this is much faster approach. i tried 5 discord servers and so many other places and no one could help me so thank you so much